# Optimization for safe switch statement

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I need to optimize a function with switch that called very often: (The idea of this function is very simply)

```
StringTable<T> *FastTableOf2( const char &seek ) {
    switch ( Count ) {
        case 256:
            return *( Children + *( byte* )&seek );
        case 10:
            if ( seek != Keys[ 9 ] )
        ...
        case 2:
            if ( seek != Keys[ 1 ] )
        case 1:
            if ( seek == Keys[ 0 ] )
                return Children[ 0 ];
            else {
            }
            else
                return Children[ 1 ];
            else
                return Children[ 2 ];
            ...
            else
                return Children[ 9 ];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I thought about checking if `Count` is 256 then do `return *( Children + *( byte* )&seek );`
and if not then do `goto case[Count]` without checking if the value is in the range of 10-1. (`Count` can be only 256 or between 1 and 10)

Is there a way to tell the compiler to just do `jmp` to label in switch instead of checking if it's in the range?
I know this optimization is very minor but every percentage counts here.

Comment: Does it help if you change `case 1` to `default`? (Not an answer since I can't test it right now).

Comment: @MikeSeymour The compiler will shrink the table and do another `jmp`. (If it isn't in the range) Tried it, but thanks.

Comment: Note that the `switch` here is tricky with `case` used as `label`. 'uncase' (as unroll for loop) may do lot of duplicate code.

Comment: Maybe you can do changes to call this method less often. You may use some memorization...

Comment: @MikeSeymour: `default` should be `return 0` as I understand (and should not be called according to OP).

Comment: @Jarod42: Only if you want error-checking rather than optimisation. But it's a moot point, since my suggestion turns out not to be an optimisation anyway.

Comment: @Jarod42 It's just to fix the compiler error that it must return something. But in real-time it can't never be at the return thing at the end of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the switch implementation is already a try to optimization,
since the code seems equivalent to:

```
StringTable<T> *FastTableOf2(const char& seek)
{
    if (Count == 256) {
        return *(Children + *(byte*)&seek);
    }
    assert(1 <= Count && Count <= 10);
    for (auto c = Count; c != 0; --c) {
        if (seek == Keys[c - 1]) {
            return Children[c - 1];
        } 
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

I would try to avoid 'gap' in the `switch` for `default`.
`default` is currently {0, [11;255], 257+}.
As `default` is not reached, you may merge it with any other `label`.

I noted that `char(256) == '\0'` so all valid values are in `[0; 10]`,
so `default` = `11+` which became `10+` by using same label as `case 11`

Alternatively, you may use `Count - 1` and merge `default` with `case 256`,
so `default` is only `11+` in both case.

That remove completely the special case `default`.

So, maybe following may be faster:

```
StringTable<T> *FastTableOf2(const char &seek ) {
    switch (char(Count)) {
        default: // Count >= 10 
        case 10: if (seek != Keys[9]) {
        ...
        case 2: if (seek != Keys[1]) {
        case 1:
            if (seek != Keys[0]) { return nullptr; } else { return Children[0]; }
            } else { return Children[1]; } // Count == 2
            } else { return Children[2]; } // Count == 3
            ...
            } else { return Children[9]; } // Count == 10
        // char(256) == '\0'
        case char(256): return *(Children + *(byte*)&seek);
    }
}
```

Comment: I alright did unrolled loop in my code. (That it's better in performance)

Comment: I have edited my answer with a possible optimization.

Answer (score 0):

For highly critical sections of code I would not use a `switch` at all, but a jump table.

In a jump table you set up an array of function pointers.  Those functions can do something very simple like return an immediate value, or do something much more complex.  Your array will have N elements in it, where N is the highest possible value you might `switch` on.

In setting up the jump table you will populate the array ahead of time, probably at program startup.  Each entry will either point to a real functon or some kind of "Unhandled" handler.

Replacing your `switch` couldn't be much simpler:

```
StringTable<T> *FastTableOf2( const char &seek ) {

  return (mJumpTable[Count])(seek);
}
```

You're not going to get much faster than this.

Comment: Some people told me to do something similar. Isn't to call a function slower? I'll try it now.

Comment: It's the same as the `jmp` you're seeking.

Comment: But it's with push seek and push this address and then jmp. I think I have an idea.

Comment: There is no seek.  You are directly addressing the function pointers in the array.

Comment: I was thinking that the compiler (may) implements `switch` by a jump table in case like this, already.

Comment: @Jarod42:  It might, but then again it might not.

Comment: @Jarod42 It's checking if it's 256 and then if it's between 10 and 1. But I don't want it to check if it's between 10 and 1. (Checked the assembly)

Comment: @JohnDibling http://pastebin.com/pwZd5aBd I tried this. But I have `C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler` :OOOO.